# LiveConect Auth (for SkyDrive) NullReferenceException (WTH)?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I followed a 43 minute video tutorial on the Channel 9 site and read the LiveConnect page where it shows code and I don't see what I'm doing wrong. It keeps giving me a NullReferenceException error and it doesn't even bring up the "Do you want to allow app X to access skydrive" thing, it just breaks immediately. I've set breakpoints everywhere but there is nothing. Just null, null everywhere.

OnNavigatedTo event:

```
LoadProfile();

private async void LoadProfile()
{
try
            {
                LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient();
                LiveLoginResult loginResult = await auth.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.basic" });
                if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    this.pageTitle.Text = "Signed in.";
                }
            }
            catch (LiveAuthException exception)
            {
                this.pageTitle.Text = "Error signing in: " + exception.Message;
            }
}
```

And the exception says:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [(C#) Azure - Null Reference Exception during Live Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487215/c-azure-null-reference-exception-during-live-authentication)

Comment: Did you register the app in the Windows Store?

Comment: @crea7or  I registered the app in the Windows Store and on the Live Connect website. Everybody keeps telling me about redirect URi'S but the tutorial says not to use redirects with Windows Store apps and instead use a Package ID but nothing says where I need to 1) get that package id from and 2) where I should put that package id. Also, on the tutorial page, I cannot proceed past step 4 because it says to go to my Dashboard and click edit then click "Advanced features" but the "Advanced features" link doesn't exist anywhere on that page anymore. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Also, a note to whoever marked this question as a duplicate: It's not a duplicate. MS says you don't use redirects with Windows Store apps and the only answer on the page you linked to says to use redirects (which doesn't work) and that answer wasn't even marked as answered. And the code is also different.

Comment: Configuring your app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826541.aspx#livesite_tailored_2 if you see that link, Step 4 tells you to click "Advanced features" after clicking edit, but after you click edit there is no advanced features anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

Subscribe to a button-click event or whatever, then use this code:

LoadProfile();

which calls this method:

```
public async void LoadProfile()
        {
            try
            {
                LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient();
                LiveLoginResult initializeResult = await auth.InitializeAsync();
                try
                {
                    LiveLoginResult loginResult = await auth.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.basic" });
                    if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
                    {
                        LiveConnectClient connect = new LiveConnectClient(auth.Session);
                        LiveOperationResult operationResult = await connect.GetAsync("me");
                        dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            this.pageTitle.Text = string.Join(" ", "Hello", result.name, "!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.pageTitle.Text = "Error getting name.";
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (LiveAuthException exception)
                {
                    this.pageTitle.Text = "Error signing in: " + exception.Message;
                }
                catch (LiveConnectException exception)
                {
                    this.pageTitle.Text = "Error calling API: " + exception.Message;
                }
            }
            catch (LiveAuthException exception)
            {
                this.pageTitle.Text = "Error initializing: " + exception.Message;
            }

        }
```

Before you debug, add your app to the Windows Store Dashboard. Then go back to Visual Studio, find Package.appxmanifest in Solution Explorer and add the Internet Capability. Then go to the Project menu > Store > Associate App with the Store.

Find your app's name in the list of apps that appears, select it and click Next/Finish and then debug. It should now be working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code instead of yours:

```
LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient();
LiveLoginResult loginResult = await auth.InitializeAsync(new string[] { "wl.basic" });
if ( loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected )
{
    LiveConnectClient connect = new LiveConnectClient( auth.Session );
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks fr the code. Same problem with it though. NullReferenceException and null values everywhere when I set breakpoint