# W8.1 Live SDK 5.6 - LiveAuthClient.InitializeAsync System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, async-await, windows-8.1, live-sdk

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 App (XAML/C#) with MVVM Light.

I used to keep my LiveId inside the code just for debugging, but now it's time to do the LogIn.

Currently i'm stuck with this piece of code:

```
this.authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
LiveLoginResult loginResult = await this.authClient.InitializeAsync(scopes);
```

It keeps giving me the error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Source Code:

```
    private static readonly string[] scopes =
            new string[] { 
               "wl.signin", 
               "wl.basic", 
               "wl.offline_access"};

    private LiveAuthClient authClient;
    private LiveConnectClient liveClient;


    public DashboardView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        this.InitializePage();
    }

    private async void InitializePage()
    {
        this.authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
        LiveLoginResult loginResult = await this.authClient.InitializeAsync(scopes);
        if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            if (this.authClient.CanLogout)
            {
                this.btnLogin.Content = "Sign Out";
            }
            else
            {
                this.btnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            this.liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(loginResult.Session);
            this.GetMe();
        }
    }

    private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.btnLogin.Content.ToString() == "Sign In")
        {
            LiveLoginResult loginResult = await this.authClient.LoginAsync(scopes);
            if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                if (this.authClient.CanLogout)
                {
                    this.btnLogin.Content = "Sign Out";
                }
                else
                {
                    this.btnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }

                this.liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(loginResult.Session);
                this.GetMe();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.authClient.Logout();
            this.btnLogin.Content = "Sign In";
        }
    }

    private async void GetMe()
    {
        Task<LiveOperationResult> task = this.liveClient.GetAsync("me");

        var result = await task;
        dynamic profile = result.Result;
    }
```

I even tried some different scopes and this was my last try.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @SonerGönül ok, i know but i initialized the var authClient. Where is the non-initialized variable in the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LiveConect Auth (for SkyDrive) NullReferenceException (WTH)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247297/liveconect-auth-for-skydrive-nullreferenceexception-wth)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Hey, thank you for your response.
I already saw that post, however i wasn't successfull.
I'm doing what the solution says, about putting the function inside an event (as it shows in the code source above).

The only thing i didn't try was associating the app with the Store, is this really necessary? Because it will be a "private" app however the user can connect using the Live Account logged in the computer.

Comment: Try it.. you never know

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov We didn't buy the Azure account yet. Associating the app to the Store means that everyone can download it?

PS: I've another app (A sample) that i downloaded and it works and i use the same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i have noticed that problem occurred in my case when calling `LiveAuthClient.LoginAsync` through interface and/or class library. In order to solve the problem I have used mediator `Messenger` class from MVVMLight library to login from application entry project which is associated with the store. To associate app with the store follow this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/708863/Developer-Guide-to-Write-Windows-Store-App-usi .

My view models are in separate (portable) library and they reference contracts library which contains interfaces for services, in order to login without getting `NullReferenceException` create a message class.

This solution is for WP8.1, but as platforms are sharing same SDK, it should work. In sample code I am using Messenger and SimpleIoc from MVVM light.

Message class:

```
public class OneDriveLoginRequestMessage
{
    public Action CallbackAction { get; set; }
}
```

Register instance of your `OneDriveClient` (or however you are calling your wrapper) I am using MVVMLight's `SimpleIoc`

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register(() => new OneDriveClient());
```

Inside `App.xaml.cs` file in method `RootFrame_FirstNavigated` add following code to login:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<OneDriveLoginRequestMessage>(this, async (msg) =>
{
    await SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<OneDriveClient>().Login();
    if (msg != null && msg.CallbackAction != null)
    {
        msg.CallbackAction();
    }
});
```

And finally to login from view model:

```
private void NavigateToOneDrivePage()
{
    MessengerInstance.Send(new OneDriveLoginRequestMessage
    {
        CallbackAction = async () =>
        {
            // after login continue here...
            var client = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<OneDriveClient>();
        }
    });
}
```

I hope that solves your problem.

Best, M

Comment: My problem was that i didn't associated with the Store... Thanks.
However i will use your code because i want to call it inside the viewmodel, i already used those messages but i didn't tought about using it to get the LiveId.